# Filter not called

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to learn with Spring Boot and I am now at the filters.

I have defined the following filter which is not called. I tested it first with debug and a breakpoint and then with hard debug (println and output).

Do I still need to register the filter or have I forgotten something?

```java
package com.example.demo.filter;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class CustumRequestFilter implements Filter
{
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        // System.out.println("Hello Filter");

        ((HttpServletResponse) request).setHeader("X-TEST-REQUEST", "FOOBAR-REQUEST");
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("X-TEST-RESPONSE", "FOOBAR-RESPONSE");

        // response.getOutputStream().write("Puff paff".getBytes());

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

- Spring Version: 6.0.7
- Spring Boot Version: 3.0.5

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter – is the filter in a package that's scanned by the component scan?

Comment: Component scan is activated in my opinion `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.demo.*"})`. With `http.addFilterAfter()` the filter is called (Example from baeldung).

Comment: @HansWurst You also have typo in CustumRequestFilter.

Comment: `scanBasePackages={"com.example.demo.*"}` is wrong and should be `scanBasePackages={"com.example.demo"}` AFAIK. Are any other beans/components successfully scanned?

Comment: @knittl With your hints and links I found the error. The IDE flagged the error: `import jakarta.servlet.*` not `import javax.servlet.*;`. In the examples javax.servlet.* was mentioned. It cannot work with the wrong interface. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use FilterRegistrationBean.

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.example.demo.filter.CustumRequestFilter;

@Configuration
public class FilterConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CustumRequestFilter> filter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<CustumRequestFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new CustumRequestFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");

        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: The actual mistake was: `import jakarta.servlet.*;` not `import javax.servlet.*;`. But that was the case in the example. Nevertheless, thank you for your configuration example.

Comment: Any idea whay is it not working with jakarta.servlet?